# Query a nested array in mongo with qualifiers

Tags: mongodb

```
arr :  [
    [a,b],
    [c,d],
    [g,i]
]
```

I want to query the above array in such manner where each array in the root array acts as the following logic:
include A or B and C or D and G and I

Basically, each nested array acts as a AND qualifier and the items within that nested array act as an OR qualifier

Update the object inside the nested array would look like this:

```
{
  "foo":{ "$oid":"615469ac6187ab0c8613b7b6"},
  "score":25,        
}
```

And I would specify the ids of the objects that I want it to match in the nested arrays

Comment: for the first part to do the and and or, i understanded it, the update you did in the question i dont understant it, can you give some sample data, what is the score? what values will have the a,b,c ...? how froom arr we got to  `{"foo" ... "score" 25}` , Give sample input data if you can and expected output data.

Answer (score 0):

Query

- reduce starting from true
- each step is like (and `$$value` (or member1 member2))

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FS9-Fg-kjiE)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$arr",
          "initialValue": true,
          "in": {
            "$and": [
              "$$value",
              {
                "$or": [
                  {
                    "$arrayElemAt": [
                      "$$this",
                      0
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "$arrayElemAt": [
                      "$$this",
                      1
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, how would I replace the initial value. As the example I mentioned was just an abstraction the actual object inside the 2d array is in the post which I have updated